# how to trigger a xe:namepicker that resides on dialogbox via csjs?

Tags: javascript, xpages

I want to trigger via csjs a xe:namepicker that resides on a dialogbox. because of that the ID of the element is not generated at first load.

the following attempts all failed:

```
var el = XSP.getElementById('#{id:npTargetFullName1}');
console.log(el.attr('class'));

var el2 = x$("#{id:npTargetFullName1}");
console.log(el2.attr('class'))

var el3 = $("[id$='npTargetFullName1']");
console.log(el3.attr('class'))
```

The next command does open the namepicker in the dialog, but the odd thing is than that the search field in the namepicker has no focus and is disabled:

```
<xe:dialog id="dlgOfficer" onShow="$('a.xspPickerLink').last().click();">
```

Comment: You could add a custom attriubte [myId=fullname1] to the namepicker, and target that in your csjs script

Comment: the namepicker does not have to the option to add custom attributes?

Comment: Try with a dojo attribute.